# lineChart Using JavaFx

Tags: javafx, linechart

I'm creating line chart using Java FX. On update, I have a list of checkbox to select or deselect the series of linechart. When all are deselected but tick points or animated tick points are there and so on by doing the same thing again or adding new data for line chart it is same. I'm unable to add images to make it easier for you. Please do some help.

private static void printChartAnalysis(analysisResults r){

```
    clearAnalsisChartData();
    int [][]analysisResult=r.getAnalysisResult();
    ArrayList<String> versionss=r.getVersions();
    int k=0;
    for(String x:versionss){
        String z=new String();
        for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++){
            if(Character.isDigit(x.charAt(i))){
                z+=x.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        dataLOC.add(new XYChart.Data(z,(int)analysisResult[k][0]));
        dataComm.add(new XYChart.Data(z,(int)analysisResult[k][1]));
        dataCond.add(new XYChart.Data(z,(int)analysisResult[k][2]));
        dataLoops.add(new XYChart.Data(z,(int)analysisResult[k][3]));
        dataMem.add(new XYChart.Data(z,(int)analysisResult[k][4]));
        k++;
    }

    seriesLOC.setData(dataLOC);
    seriesCond.setData(dataCond);
    seriesComm.setData(dataComm);
    seriesLoop.setData(dataLoops);
    seriesMem.setData(dataMem);        
    lineChart.getData().setAll(seriesLOC,seriesComm,seriesCond,seriesLoop,seriesMem);
    lineChart.setTitle("Line Chart for "+r.getSoftwareName());

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        final CheckBox cb = cbs[i];
        cb.setSelected(true);
    }

}

private static void printChartCost(cocomoResults est){
    clearAnalsisChartData();
    clearCostChartData();
    for(COCOMO cost:est.getVersionsResult()){
         String version=cost.getVersion();
         String z=new String();

         for(int i=0;i<version.length();i++){
            if(Character.isDigit(version.charAt(i))){
                z+=version.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        dataEffort.add(new XYChart.Data(z,(int)cost.getEffort()));
        dataDura.add(new XYChart.Data(z,(int)cost.getDuration()));
        dataStaff.add(new XYChart.Data(z,(int)cost.getStaff()));
        dataProd.add(new XYChart.Data(z,(int)cost.getProductivity()));

    }

    seriesEffort.setData(dataEffort);
    seriesDura.setData(dataDura);
    seriesStaff.setData(dataStaff);
    seriesProd.setData(dataProd);

    lineChart.getData().setAll(seriesEffort,seriesDura,seriesStaff,seriesProd);

}

private static void clearAnalsisChartData(){
    lineChart.getData().removeAll(seriesLOC);
    lineChart.getData().removeAll(seriesComm);
    lineChart.getData().removeAll(seriesCond);
    lineChart.getData().removeAll(seriesLoop);
    lineChart.getData().removeAll(seriesMem);

    dataLOC.clear();
    dataLoops.clear();
    dataComm.clear();
    dataCond.clear();
    dataMem.clear();

}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried.

Comment: Upload to http://imgur.com/ and append the link to your question as a plain text.

Comment: I've uploaded images pleaes take a look. Thank you. http://imgur.com/K556dDb, http://imgur.com/Bywhoc3, http://imgur.com/ZaBZS3F

Comment: Show the code where you add the tick points to the chart.

Comment: i've added code in my post please take a look. @UlukBiy

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood

```
cb.setOnAction(event -> {
   if (lineChart.contains(*NAME_OF_YOUR_ELEMENT*))
      lineChart.remove(*NAME_OF_YOUR_ELEMENT*)
   else
      lineChart.remove(*NAME_OF_YOUR_ELEMENT*)
});
```